# cfinput minimum password length

Tags: coldfusion

How can the cfinput tag be set to validate the minimum input length? (E.g. To a minimum of 8 characters long)

Currently have:

```
<cfinput type="password" name="password " label="Password" required="yes" 
      message="Please Enter Your Password">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use Regular Expression which will validate for a pattern with length between 8 and 16, allowing upper and lower case letters, numbers, periods, and underscores.

```
<cfinput type="password" name="password " label="Password" required="yes" validate="regex" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._]{8,16}$" message="Please Enter Your Password">
```

Comment: label="Password" usually doesn't do anything... unless you're using XForm/FlashForm with CFFORM... :S

Comment: Just want to find out, how can this be done as a server side validation and not client side? For if the client disables javascript, then the validations wont work, thus server side is needed.

Comment: Nich ideally you would want to have both client and server side validation.

Answer (score 2):

```
       <script>
        function validatePassword(pass) {   
            //custom javascript code
            alert(pass.length);
        }
        </script>

        <cfform name="registration">
        <cfinput id="password" 
                type="password" 
                name="password" 
                label="Password" 
                required="yes" 
                message="Please Enter Your Password" 
                onkeyup="javascript:validatePassword(this.value);" />
        </cfform>
```

Or something like that... Just disable submit button until you get upto 8 chars, and/or display some red/green info etc...